# What does -march=native boil down to?

Tags: gcc, compiler-options

Currently we compile and run code on same hardware, so `-march=native` flag is used.

We are going to keep running on this hardware but compile on different architecture. So I need to replace `native` with whatever it is equivalent to on current hardware.

Is there a way to get `gcc` to report what `native` is equivalent to on particular hardware?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can run the command

```
gcc -march=native -Q --help=target
```

to see the flags applied, including the resolved -march flag.

Comment: We have  Intel Xeon Gold 6148 dual-socket nodes, and `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target` reported `-march = knl'.

This is surprising to me - we don't have any Phi accelerators. Is it expected?

Comment: @user2052436 you should ask that as a different question